Angular Calendar Warning: NG0956 - Track by identity caused re-creation of the entire collection
I'm using nz-calendar from ng-zorro-antd in my Angular application. Every time I click on a date in the calendar, I receive the following warning in the console:
NG0956: The configured tracking expression (track by identity) caused re-creation of the entire collection of size 7. This is an expensive operation requiring destruction and subsequent creation of DOM nodes, directives, components etc. Please review the "track expression" and make sure that it uniquely identifies items in a collection. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0956.
My HTML:
<nz-calendar [nzFullscreen]="false" [(ngModel)]="currentDate" [nzCustomHeader]="customHeader"
  (nzSelectChange)="onDateChange($event)" nzTooltipVisible="false">
  <div class="dot" *nzDateCell="let date;" style="list-style: none;">
    <nz-badge *ngIf="isSelected(date)" nzStatus="warning"></nz-badge>
  </div>
</nz-calendar>

Component:
currentDate: Date = this.calendarService.getCurrentDate();
selectedDates: Set<string> = new Set<string>();

isSelected(date: Date): boolean {
    const formattedDate = date.toISOString();
    const isMatched = this.selectedDates.has(formattedDate);

    return isMatched;
}

onDateChange(newDate: Date): void {
  console.log('newDate :>> ', newDate);
  this.calendarService.setCurrentDate(newDate);
}

updateSelectedDates(data: any): void {
  this.selectedDates.clear();
  data.forEach((appointment: any) => {
    const appointmentDate = new Date(appointment.appointment_date);
    appointmentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.selectedDates.add(appointmentDate.toISOString());
  });
  this.cdr.markForCheck();
}

Service:
private currentDate = new BehaviorSubject<Date>(new Date());

getCurrentDate(): Date {
  return this.currentDate.value;
}

Dependencies:
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^18.0.6",
  "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "^18.0.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
  "ng-zorro-antd": "^18.0.1",
  "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
  "ngx-scrollbar": "^15.1.2",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.3"

 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

Problem:
I suspect the warning is related to how Angular is tracking the nzDateCell elements, causing re-creation of the DOM nodes when I click on a date. I tried using trackBy, but I'm not sure how to implement it with nzDateCell.
Question:
How can I properly use trackBy with nzDateCell or otherwise resolve this issue to avoid re-creating the entire collection every time a date is clicked?

issue not reproducible stackblitz

I’ve fully updated the code and was surprised to see that there are no warnings when using StackBlitz. However, I’m encountering a warning locally. If I ignore this warning, could it cause any issues?

try checking the error stacktrace, to identify whether the bug is from the code you shared, or somewhere else in your application

You mean to check other components related to the calendar component, right?

yes, the error, will contain the exact location where the issue occours, you need to check the stacktrace in the developer console.

link
This warning appears every time you select a date in the calendar or press the next or previous button in the app.


This is a warning, it does not block your development.
It is mostly related to a problem in the package and not due to the code you wrote for implementation.
The red background messages are the important errors to fix, but since this is from the library level you can ignore this and proceed with development.

In summary, it's not related to tracking structural directives as in the warning complaint, right?

@JarMoo Yes, its a optimization warning, it does not break any code and can be ignored

I don't think it's a good idea to "ignore" warnings.
Tracking expression caused re-creation of the DOM structure.
The identity track expression specified in the @for loop caused re-creation of the DOM corresponding to all items. This is a very expensive operation that commonly occurs when working with immutable data structures. For example:
@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggleAllDone()">All done!</button>
    <ul>
    @for (todo of todos; track todo) {
      <li>{{todo.task}}</li>
    }
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  todos = [
    { id: 0, task: 'understand trackBy', done: false },
    { id: 1, task: 'use proper tracking expression', done: false },
  ];
  toggleAllDone() {
    this.todos = this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, done: true }));
  }
}

In the provided example, the entire list with all the views (DOM nodes, Angular directives, components, queries, etc.) are re-created (!) after toggling the "done" status of items. Here, a relatively inexpensive binding update to the done property would suffice.
Apart from having a high performance penalty, re-creating the DOM tree results in loss of state in the DOM elements (ex.: focus, text selection, sites loaded in an iframe, etc.).
Fixing the error :
Change the tracking expression such that it uniquely identifies an item in a collection, regardless of its object identity. In the discussed example, the correct track expression would use the unique id property (item.id):
@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggleAllDone()">All done!</button>
    <ul>
    @for (todo of todos; track todo.id) {
      <li>{{todo.task}}</li>
    }
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  todos = [
    { id: 0, task: 'understand trackBy', done: false },
    { id: 1, task: 'use proper tracking expression', done: false },
  ];
  toggleAllDone() {
    this.todos = this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, done: true }));
  }
}

https://angular.dev/errors/NG0956
